# How to restrict some items to be not selected in CComboBox?

Tags: mfc

In a MFC dialog box I am using `CComboBox` with `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`. It is an ownerdrawn `CComboBox`.

I am listing Group name and items of group in the listbox. Using the source code given in the link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/450/CComboBox-with-disabled-items.

When I select or click group name, the edit control of `CComboBox` should not be updated group item text. In that link they are doing the following things to get rid of selection group item.

- Overriding the `WM_LBUTTONUP` handler of the enclosed list box, we can actually disable clicking on the group items.
- Overriding `CharToItem` handler, we can disable picking the group items by keyboard.
- And finally, by reacting to reflected `CBN_SELENDOK`, we can assure that a group item was not selected.

```cpp
const UINT nMessage=::RegisterWindowMessage("ComboSelEndOK");

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CODrawCombo, CComboBox)
ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(CBN_SELENDOK, OnSelendok)
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(nMessage, OnRealSelEndOK)
ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(CBN_EDITUPDATE, OnComboEdited)
ON_MESSAGE(WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX, OnCtlColor)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CODrawCombo::OnSelendok() 
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    GetWindowText(m_strSavedText);
    PostMessage(nMessage);  
}

LRESULT CODrawCombo::OnRealSelEndOK(WPARAM,LPARAM)
{
    CString currentText;
    GetWindowText(currentText);

    int index=FindStringExact(-1,currentText);
    if (index>=0 && !IsItemEnabled)
    {
        SetWindowText(m_strSavedText);
        GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND,MAKELONG(GetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_ID),CBN_SELCHANGE),(LPARAM)m_hWnd);
    }
    return 0;
}

void CListBoxInsideComboBox::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    CRect rect; GetClientRect(rect);

    if (rect.PtInRect(point))
    {
        BOOL outside=FALSE;
        int index=((CListBox *)this)->ItemFromPoint(point,outside);
        if (!outside && !m_Parent->IsItemEnabled(index))
            return; // don't click there
    }

    CWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}
```

[image]

After clicking group item and if I click outside of `CListBox`, the edit control of `CComboBox` updated with group name only? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is prepared to respond to `CBN_SELENDOK`, but is not prepared when the user makes a list selection and then cancels the selection.

You can respond to `CBN_SELENDCANCEL` notification as well. While you are at it, you may want to respond to `CBN_SELCHANGE` so that the user cannot change to invalid selection using the keyboard.

```
ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(CBN_SELENDCANCEL, CheckIfEnabled)
ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(CBN_SELCHANGE, CheckIfEnabled)
...
int m_save_index;
...
CExtendedComboBox::CExtendedComboBox()
{
    m_save_index = 0;
    m_ListBox.SetParent(this);
}

void CExtendedComboBox::OnSelendok()
{
    GetWindowText(m_strSavedText);
    PostMessage(nMessage);
    int index = GetCurSel();
    if(index >= 0 && IsItemEnabled(index))
        m_save_index = index;
}

void CExtendedComboBox::CheckIfEnabled()
{
    int index = GetCurSel();
    if(index >= 0 && !IsItemEnabled(index))
        SetCurSel(m_save_index);
}
```

By the way, the code from codeproject link is a bit old. To properly subclass the combobox's listbox, use `GetComboBoxInfo` and subclass a `CListBox`. I am not sure what is the purpose of `PostMessage` and `OnRealSelEndOK` and some of the other functions listed there.

Comment: CBN_SELENDCANCEL sets the current index but the edit control of combobx showing groupname only.

Comment: You also have to enable modern UI look to use updated version of common control library.